# Real Time camera degrees on screen

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am trying to get de real time camera/cursor position in a text field in aframe. I found some tips but still havn't got it working(don't get any positions). 
This is what i got so far. I am not that experienced in aframe, js so hope you don't blame me.

```
<html>
<body>
<a-entity position="0 -2 0">
      <a-camera rotation-reader>
        <a-cursor color="white"></a-cursor>
      </a-camera>
</a-entity> 

<a-entity id="positieX" bmfont-text="text: X" position="1 0.5 -2"></a-entity>
      <a-entity id="positieY" bmfont-text="text: Y" position="1 0 -2"></a-entity>
      <a-entity id="positieZ" bmfont-text="text: Z" position="1 -0.5 -2"></a-entity>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function()
       {

        var rotation = document.getElementById('positieX')
        var y = document.getElementById('positieY')
        var z = document.getElementById('positieZ')
        console.log("1")

        AFRAME.registerComponent('rotation-reader', {
        schema: {type: 'string'},

        init: function () {
            var rotation1 = this.data;
            rotation.setAttribute('bmfont-text', rotation1);

  }
});
    console.log("2")
    });
```

This is what i want it to do. If someone is looking to te left i want te get the number of degrees he is looking to te right, up and down. Same thing for looking to the left.

Comment: *This is what i want it to do. If someone is looking to te left i want te get the number of degrees he is looking to te left, up and down. Same thing for looking to the right.

Comment: "still havn't got it working" what is not working? [edit] the question and describe what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize the `tick` function. It is called on each render loop, so it's as realtime as you can get. On each tick you can get the rotation, and do whatever you need.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function() {
    this.camera = document.querySelector("[camera]")
  },
  tick: function() {
    var rotation = this.camera.getAttribute("rotation")
    //set the text components value accordingly to rotation.x, rotation.y
  }
})
```

check it out on my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9arwLqn/10/)

Comment: Looks pretty nice man, wil take a good look at it so i understand it all